# My code run in loop

Tags: php

I know this is not the kind of question that I can ask here but my code run in loop and I don't know why :

```
   while ($resultat = $resultats->fetch())
        {

           $checkBadMetier = $connexion->prepare("SELECT onetsoc_code
                                FROM badQuestionMetier
                                WHERE element_id = '$key' AND onetsoc_code='$resultat->onetsoc_code'");
            $checkBadMetier->execute(); //line 125!!
            $res = $checkBadMetier->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
            if (count($res) > 0) {
                $jobTable[$resultat->onetsoc_code]=-900000;
            }
```

It's make the PHP timeout any idea why?

Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 120 seconds exceeded on line *125*

Comment: Your script runs longer than 120 seconds that's basically what that error means.

Comment: check the amount of data that is present in your database, that is coing in resultstats, might be too much data is present in it that is taking more time than 120 seconds to complete the execution

Comment: Yes but the database is really small http://imgur.com/cXXIWZn and without this small code, it's works fine

Answer (score 0):

Your loop might be endless. If it is not, you could extend the maximum execution time like this:

```
ini_set('max_execution_time', 300); //300 seconds = 5 minutes
```

Comment: Yes but it's not supposed to take so much time, without this code it's take 5-10 seconds and with it, it's timeout, here a pic of the database and it's small : http://imgur.com/cXXIWZn